# ArrayList de 2 dimensões

Tags: java

Comecei há pouco tempo a trabalhar com `ArrayList`, mas a minha questão é como criar uma matriz de `ArrayList`.

Comment: Talvez ajude nesse seu caso de estudo, dessa forma você teria uma lista de listas de String  `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matriz = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Ok ja entendi mas como faço para adicionar e acessar a matriz?

Comment: A questão é: o que você pretende fazer com essa matriz de `ArrayList`? Eu acho que o que você realmente quer é um `Map`, mas para ter certeza, é necessário saber-se o que você quer fazer com essa matriz.

Answer (score 1):

O `ArrayList` (ou mais exatamente, a interface `List`, há um princípio de programação que diz que você deve codificar para uma interface, e não uma implementação) frequentemente é utilizada como um substituto para os arrays. Usar um `List` ao invés de um array tem várias vantagens:

- Misturar arrays e tipos genéricos é um tanto problemático. Utilizar `List` com tipos genéricos é bem mais fácil e conveniente.
- Arrays têm tamanho fixo. `List` tem tamanho variável. Em especial, ao acrescentar-se um elemento na `List`, ela cresce.
- `List` já vem com diversos métodos úteis para manipular-se os dados de diversas formas, arrays não.

Entretanto, para o casos de matrizes, não há um bom substituto para o `List`. Para entender o porquê e como resolver essa situação, vamos pensar num pouco no que são matrizes.

- Uma matriz é conceitualmente uma grade de `m × n` elementos, onde `m` e `n` são as dimensões. Matrizes também podem ter mais do que duas dimensões.
- Em Java (e na maioria das linguagens descendentes do C), matrizes são representadas como arrays de arrays.
- Uma vez que `List`s têm tamanho variável, ao transportar-se esse conceito para matrizes, não fica claro o que ocorre. Ao acrescentar-se um elemento em uma matriz de tamanho variável, em que linha ou coluna ele seria acrescentado? Aliás, matrizes de tamanho variável fazem algum sentido afinal?

Uma possível abordagem seria trocar uma matriz `X[][]` por uma lista `ArrayList<ArrayList<X>>` (ou melhor, `List<List<X>>`). Entretanto, essa abordagem tem um sério problema, que é o de não dar para sair atribuindo elementos diretamente na nela tal como poderia ser feito com uma matriz baseada em arrays. Por exemplo:

```
String[][] a = new String[10][10];
a[0][0] = "abc"; // Funciona ok.

List<List<String>> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.get(0).set(0, "abc"); // NullPointerException!
```

O problema aqui é que as listas correspondentes às linhas da matriz não foram devidamente instanciadas.

Um outro problema dessa abordagem é que não dá para garantir que todas as linhas da matriz terão o mesmo comprimento. Por exemplo:

```
List<List<String>> c = new ArrayList<>();
c.add(new ArrayList<>());
c.add(new ArrayList<>());
c.get(0).add("a");
c.get(0).add("b");
c.get(0).add("c");
c.get(1).add("x");
```

Nesse exemplo, a primeira linha da "matriz" ficou com três elementos enquanto que a segunda linha ficou com um. Matrizes com linhas de tamanho distintos são uma aberração e não deveriam existir. Entretanto, essa mesma aberração também pode ocorrer no caso de arrays:

```
String[][] d = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"x"}};
```

Esse problema advém do fato de estarmos representando matrizes como arrays de arrays ou como listas de listas, onde cada lista ou array interno representa uma linha e não há garantia de que todas as linhas terão o mesmo tamanho.

Por outro lado, há um truque matemático possível para representar elementos dispostos em várias dimensões em uma única dimensão. Podemos representar uma matriz de `m × n` elementos com um array ou lista de `m × n` elementos e determinar que cada bloco de `n` elementos constitui uma linha, havendo um total de `m` blocos no array ou lista. Entretando, esse nosso conceito de matriz constitui-se em um tipo de objeto, e portanto convém colocá-lo em uma classe. Além disso, esse truque utilizado para armazenar-se os elementos constitui-se de uma regra interna de funcionamento da nossa definição da nossa matriz, e se é uma regra interna, deve ser encapsulada. Assim sendo:

```
public class Matriz2<V> {
    private final int linhas;
    private final int colunas;
    private final List<V> elementos;

    public Matriz2(int linhas, int colunas) {
         this.linhas = linhas;
         this.colunas = colunas;
         elementos = new ArrayList<>(linhas * colunas);
    }

    public boolean posicaoValida(int linha, int coluna) {
        return linha >= 0 && linha < linhas && coluna >= 0 && coluna < colunas;
    }

    private int posicaoNaLista(int linha, int coluna) {
        if (!posicaoValida(linha, coluna)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return linha * colunas + coluna;
    }

    private int linhaDaPosicao(int posicao) {
        return posicao / colunas;
    }

    private int colunaDaPosicao(int posicao) {
        return posicao % colunas;
    }

    public void set(int linha, int coluna, V elemento) {
        if (!posicaoValida(linha, coluna)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        elementos.set(posicaoNaLista(linha, coluna), elemento);
    }

    public V get(int linha, int coluna) {
        if (!posicaoValida(linha, coluna)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return elementos.get(posicaoNaLista(linha, coluna));
    }
}
```

Você pode acrescentar os métodos que preferir nessa classe. A complexidade de converter-se de um conjunto `[linha, coluna]` para uma posição na lista é dada pelo método `posicaoNaLista`. Como isso é uma regra interna da nossa representação de matriz, esse método é privado. Os métodos `linhaDaPosicao` e `colunaDaPosicao` servem para fazer o mapeamento inverso.

Você também pode aplicar esse mesmo conceito para três dimensões:

```
public class Matriz3<V> {
    private final int linhas;
    private final int colunas;
    private final int paginas;
    private final List<V> elementos;

    public Matriz3(int linhas, int colunas, paginas) {
         this.linhas = linhas;
         this.colunas = colunas;
         this.paginas = paginas;
         elementos = new ArrayList<>(linhas * colunas * paginas);
    }

    public boolean posicaoValida(int linha, int coluna, int pagina) {
        return linha >= 0 && linha < linhas && coluna >= 0 && coluna < colunas && pagina >= 0 && pagina < paginas;
    }

    private int posicaoNaLista(int linha, int coluna, int pagina) {
        if (!posicaoValida(linha, coluna, pagina)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return pagina * linhas * colunas + linha * colunas + coluna;
    }

    private int paginaDaPosicao(int posicao) {
        return posicao / (linhas * colunas);
    }

    private int linhaDaPosicao(int posicao) {
        return (posicao % (linhas * colunas) / colunas;
    }

    private int colunaDaPosicao(int posicao) {
        return posicao % colunas;
    }

    public void set(int linha, int coluna, int pagina, V elemento) {
        if (!posicaoValida(linha, coluna, pagina)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        elementos.set(posicaoNaLista(linha, coluna, pagina), elemento);
    }

    public V get(int linha, int coluna, int pagina) {
        if (!posicaoValida(linha, coluna, pagina)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return elementos.get(posicaoNaLista(linha, coluna, pagina));
    }
}
```